# Bottle with SQLAlchemy on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, sqlalchemy, bottle

I am trying to setup a simple server on heroku using bottle and sqlalchemy but I keep getting the error that I have not given my methods enough arguments because the "db" keyword is not getting injected.
Here is what I tried:

```
import os
from bottle import *
import bottle
from bottle.ext import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Sequence, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import json

app = bottle.Bottle()
database_url = os.environ["DATABASE_URL"]

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(database_url, echo=True)

plugin = sqlalchemy.Plugin(
        engine,
        Base.metadata,
        keyword='db',
        create=True,
        commit=True,
        use_kwargs=False
)

app.install(plugin)

class Path(Base):
    __tablename__ = "path"
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence("id_seq"), primary_key=True)
    start_node = Column(String)
    end_node = Column(String)
    path = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, start_node, end_node, path):
        self.start_node = start_node
        self.end_node = end_node
        self.path = path

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Path(id: '%d', start_node: '%s', end_node: '%s', path: '%s')>" & (self.id, self.start_node, self.end_node, self.path)

@app.get("/get", db)
def node_value(db):
    node = "face"
    start_path = db.query(Path).filter_by(start_node=node)
    end_path = db.query(Path).filter_by(end_node=node)
    if start_path and end_path:
        data = start_node
        data.append(end_path)
    if start_path:
        return start_node
    if end_path:
        return end_path
    else:
        return "ERROR"


@route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"

run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 3000)))
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Take the `db` argument out of your decorator.

Comment: Oops. That was me testing random things. I did that and changed the decorator back to `@route("/get")`. But I still get the same error. It says that it received 0 arguments but was expecting 1.

Comment: I think you need to add `db` into `hello_world()`'s arguments as well.

Comment: I added that but the problem still remains that node_value() is expecting to receive the db argument that it is not getting.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it worked for me.  The only things I changed seem inconsistent with what you describe as your experience, but maybe they will help:

1. Removed the `db` param from your `app.get` decoration.
2. You need to call *your app's* run method, not bottle's.  I.e.,

So these two lines changed from:

```
@app.get("/get", db)
...
run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 3000)))
```

to

```
@app.get("/get")
...
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 3000)))
```

Then it works as expected.  If these changes don't solve your problem, please post exactly what you're doing to generate the error message and what the message is, and I'll see if I can reproduce it on my end.

PS, When I say it "works for me," I mean that the `node_value` method gets called, per original Q.  I'm not saying it actually *does* anything.  :)  Oh, FYI I also set DATABASE_URL to "sqlite:///:memory:"